# Rails: How do I make a button that calls a custom controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model `entry` which has field `done:boolean`
I would like to create a button "mark as done" on the entries index which sets `done` of that entry to true.
[image: entries]

In entries controller:

```
def set_done
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:entry_id])
  @entry.done = true
end
```

In entries index (view):

```
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
  <% if entry.user.id == @user %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= entry.content %></td>
      <td><%= entry.due_date %></td>
      <td><%= entry.user_id %></td>
      <td><%= entry.done %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Mark as Done',  entry_set_done_path(entry), method: :put %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_entry_path(entry) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', entry, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In routes:

```
resources :entries do
  resources :tags
  put '/set_done', to: 'entries#set_done'
end
```

Result of `rails routes`:

```
entry_set_done   PUT     /entries/:entry_id/set_done(.:format)     entries#set_done
```

There's no error (stays on the same page), but the value of done doesn't change
Bash Console rails server output

```
Started PUT "/entries/15/set_done" for ::1 at 2020-01-01 20:38:32 +0800
Processing by EntriesController#set_done as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"CCjQWigTo19T7RKNMHpOZI05t/2z36iCr1yZCFB5fBxp75wJFF9rFtMlQOO0wPuxytRzFNkF+fczNUFNHRyDtw==", "entry_id"=>"15"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
No template found for EntriesController#set_done, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 2031)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the error, you passing `GET` - but your route waiting for `PUT`.

You can pass `:method` option to `link_to` to set proper one. [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

So result will be something like this

```
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
  <% if entry.user.id == @user %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= entry.content %></td>
      <td><%= entry.due_date %></td>
      <td><%= entry.user_id %></td>
      <td><%= entry.done %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Mark as Done', method: :put,  entry_set_done_path(entry), method: :put %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_entry_path(entry) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', entry, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I've changed the routing to a PUT (updated the post), is that not correct?

Comment: Looks like correct.  But also you need to fix your `set_done` method. Add `@entry.save` in the end to save your model :) (or change `@entry.done = true` to `@entry.update(done: true)`